# How to remove the vertical space between two images latex

Tags: graphics, floats

I know this topic is allready discussed but I still don't manage to solve this problem. I have 2 pictures in my document. I would like to delete the white vertical space between them. I found something about floatsep but it seems not work. I just have 2 simple images:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.37]{Cube.png}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.37]{Cog.png}
\end{figure}
```

What do I have to add to solve this problem? And where I have to do it? Thank you!

Comment: Please read the answers to http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39017/5763 for why `[H]` is normally a bad idea.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can combine the contents of the separate `figure` environments into one:

```
\begin{figure}[htb]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[scale=0.37]{Cube.png}

  \vspace{<whatever>}

  \includegraphics[scale=0.37]{Cog.png}
\end{figure}
```

Now you can supply a space of `<whatever>` to adequately separate the images. If you don't want any space, just remove the `\vspace` command but keep an empty line between the two included images. Some suggestions:

- The `[H]` float specifier (from the [`float` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/float)) doesn't help here, since you're keeping things together anyway. For more on float placement, see [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39017/5764);
- Scaling an inserted image using `scale` is *okay*. However, in most cases it's better to use a `width` or `height` key-value. This way you can ensure the two images are of the same size. Use, for example, `width=0.5\linewidth`.

Comment: It works perfectly! Thank you for your suggestions as well!

Comment: what do you when both the figures include sub-figures ?

Comment: @DineshVG: If you're using the [`subcaption` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/subcaption), then you can set the `\subcaptionbox` (or whatever) *without* a blank line between them (perhaps spacing them using `\hspace{<len>}`) while you *do include* a blank line between the regular figure `\caption`s like above. See [this example paste](http://pastebin.com/KBTE3z2h) and its [corresponding output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q7t3l.png).

Comment: Could we also give a sub-caption names to the images placed inside the subcaptionboxes?

Answer (score 1):

For one caption for both figures, you can try something like this

```
\begin{figure}[!t]
%first figure 
\begin{minipage}[h]{1.0\linewidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{xomp}
\end{minipage}

\vspace{0.00mm} 

%second figure 
\begin{minipage}[h]{0.5\linewidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{ins}
\end{minipage}   

%\vspace{0.00mm} 

%third figure 
%..
%..
\caption{one caption for both figure}
\label{fig:1}
\end{figure}
```

source: https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=8844